# Access data inside stdObject

Tags: php

I have stdClass data after submitting the form:

```
"Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [username] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [0] => 1001037
                    [1] => AARONJAMES
                    [2] => 1
                    [3] => ULTIMA (Red)
                    [4] => 1001037|1
                    [staff_id] => 1001037
                    [username] => AARONJAMES
                    [fkhouseid] => 1
                    [hname] => ULTIMA (Red)
                    [id] => 1001037|1
                    [$$hashKey] => object:13
                )

            [$$hashKey] => object:6
            [points] => 50
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [username] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [0] => 1001075
                    [1] => AARONKOH
                    [2] => 2
                    [3] => NACHOZZ (Purple)
                    [4] => 1001075|2
                    [staff_id] => 1001075
                    [username] => AARONKOH
                    [fkhouseid] => 2
                    [hname] => NACHOZZ (Purple)
                    [id] => 1001075|2
                    [$$hashKey] => object:14
                )

            [house] => 
            [points] => 20
            [$$hashKey] => object:306
        )

)"
```

I want to access `id` variable inside username array to explode it later and insert data into database. 
I tried to use to access it but it didnt work:

```
foreach ($persons as $key => $object) {
  var_dump($persons[$key]->id);
}
```

How can I access `id` variable inside username?

Comment: `$persons[$key]->username->id;`?

Comment: try this `$persons[0]->username->id`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$persons` have array. You can try like below.

```
foreach ($persons as $key => $object) {
  var_dump($object->username->id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments you should try this

```
foreach ($persons as $key => $object) {
 echo $object[$key]->username->id;
}
```

some details about array

1. `$key` is the `index` number of person array.
2. username is the `stdClass Object` so you can get like this `->username`.